# Javascript setTimeout + loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to loop some div's, and I have that code:

```
var first = ".first";
for (i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(first).delay(500).animate({
            "opacity": "1"
        }, 1500);
        $(first).delay(1500).animate({
            "opacity": "0"
        }, 1500);
        $(".1").delay(4500).animate({
            "opacity": "1"
        }, 1500);
        $(".1").delay(1500).animate({
            "opacity": "0"
        }, 1500);

        $(".2").delay(4800).animate({
            "opacity": "1"
        }, 1500);
        $(".2").delay(1500).animate({
            "opacity": "0"
        }, 1500);

        $(".3").delay(5300).animate({
            "opacity": "1"
        }, 1500);
        $(".3").delay(1500).animate({
            "opacity": "0"
        }, 1500);

        $(".4").delay(5600).animate({
            "opacity": "1"
        }, 1500);
        $(".4").delay(1500).animate({
            "opacity": "0"
        }, 1500);

        $(".5").delay(5900).animate({
            "opacity": "1"
        }, 1500);
        $(".5").delay(1500).animate({
            "opacity": "0"
        }, 1500);
    }, 6000);
}
```

I tried without setTimeout and effect was the same - divs was appeared and disappeared only in 1st loop. In each next loop they're appeared in random order. I know, that method is wrong, but I'm green with JavaScript and I have no idea how to do it correct. Someone can help me?

Comment: animate works asynchronously, thus they all start working at the same moment for you.
There's a third argument you can pass to animate, is callback, an anonymous function that does something when animation completed, try to make something with that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing functions to setTimeout in a loop: always the last value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425062/passing-functions-to-settimeout-in-a-loop-always-the-last-value) and a gazillion others

Comment: could you explain what effect are you trying to get

Comment: @MattBall I disagree, the OP does not use any variables in setTimeout's callback function (except `first` which does not change anyway).

Comment: @MattBall OP is not passing any value

Comment: People, please answer the questions at box below, to remove them from unanswered list.

Comment: also, you can try using .promise() to make your animation go step by step.

Comment: using timeout like this in a loop gives the feeling that only one is fired because your loop takes nano second to execute. UPDATE: see @epascarello's answer (and upvote it...)

Answer (score 1):

It is because the for loop keep attaching events and you are 9999 animations to the same element with no delay. They are just pounding on each other. The code makes no sense.

If you want the code to run in a loop, you can use a callback in one of the animations and call a function when it is done. Other option is to use a Interval, but that gets messy with timing events not being accurate and they can pile up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to make the elements animate seemingly indefinitely by running a setTimeout timer a large number of times. For that you should instead use `setInterval()` to have the function run every 6 seconds.

So, instead of...

```
for (i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(first).delay(500).animate({
            "opacity": "1"
        }, 1500);

        // etc etc

    }, 6000);
}
```

...do this:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $(first).delay(500).animate({
        "opacity": "1"
    }, 1500);

    // etc etc

}, 6000);
```

(note: no for loop.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/57sYA/

Comment: `setInterval` should not be used for this purpose. It assumes that the async code that jQuery runs internally will remain perfectly in sync with your `setInterval`, which is highly unlikely.

Comment: @BlueSkies I don't see why they should stay in sync in this case.

Comment: @BlueSkies Ok, the `delay()` + animation duration is longer than the interval length for most of the elements, which probably messes up the intended effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution of my problem - setInterval

```
    var licznik=0;
function show_anim(){
         if(licznik!=9999){
         $("#first").delay(500).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1500);
         $("#first").delay(1500).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1500);
         $("#1").delay(4500).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1500);
         $("#1").delay(1500).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1500);

         $("#2").delay(4800).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1500);
         $("#2").delay(1500).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1500);

         $("#3").delay(5300).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1500);
         $("#3").delay(1500).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1500);

         $("#4").delay(5600).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1500);
         $("#4").delay(1500).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1500);

         $("#5").delay(5900).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 1500);
         $("#5").delay(1500).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1500);
         licznik++;
         console.log(licznik);
         }
   }

$(document).ready(function(){

show_anim()


setInterval("show_anim()",12000);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D5bxA/