# javascript - execute a for loop with time intervals

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, intervals

I have this "for" loop that calls a function for ids named b1,b2,b3

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        editorfunction("b" + i);
        }
```

But the effect of this code need to be run with intervals of time.
That means after editorfunction affects b1, there should be 1 second time space and then the action should be applied for b2, like that.

I tried this

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        //editorfunction("b" + i);
        setInterval(function () {editorfunction("b" + i);}, 1000; }
        }
```

But it does not work. How can I make it work?

Comment: The answer below gives you `1000*i` which is correct, but then you're going to encounter the second problem, which the duplicate explains.

Comment: @elclanrs This question is not a duplicate of the one you proposed, and the answer below has since been deleted.

Comment: I see a clear dup... here's another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425062/passing-functions-to-settimeout-in-a-loop-always-the-last-value. OP wants `setTimeout` probably.

Comment: @elclanrs That second one is a lot more apropos. The original you used only answers a portion of OP's problem, as you yourself alluded.