# jquery double function each

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have the following block of HTML code more than once

```
<div id="page_1" class="page">
<div class="imageDetail_bg">
    <img src="../_img/detail_car.jpg" alt="" id="car_detail" class="car_detail"/>
</div><!-- imageDetail-->

    <div id="listThumbs">
     <div id="thumbsContainer_1" class="thumbsContainer">
        <div id="areaThumb" class="areaThumb">
        <div id="posThumb_1" class="posThumb">
            <img src="../_img/detail_car.jpg" class="detail_img" alt="">
        </div>
        </div><!--areaThumb-->

        <div id="areaThumb" class="areaThumb">
        <div id="posThumb_2" class="posThumb">
             <img src="../_img/detail_car.jpg" class="detail_img" alt="" />
        </div>
        </div><!--areaThumb--> 
            ...
            ...
            ...
</div><!--listThumbs-->
 </div><!--page-->
```

and the following jQuery code:

```
 $('.page').each(function(i) {
        $('.areaThumb').each(function(j) {
            $('.detail_img').eq(j).click(function(){
                $('.car_detail').eq(i).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
            });
        });
});
```

What I want to do is: For each page there's a block of thumbs, and when I click in any thumb, the image in #car_detail is replaced by the image of the thumb I clicked. At this moment I can do this, BUT the #car_detail image is replaced in all pages. I'm not getting individually actions for each page. Every click make the action occurs in all pages.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean ID or class of `car_detail`? The code says one thing, and the question text says another.

Comment: Initially I had id, but for affecting all car_detail (because I have more than one) I changed to class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not iterate through each element of the jquery selector result to bind a click event.
And you are missing a closing div for thumbsContainer div, add that before each .

Also if you have an element with id car_detail then you should use `#car_detail` instead of `.car_detail`

Working example @ http://jsfiddle.net/2ZQ6b/

Try this:

```
$(".page .areaThumb .detail_img").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("div.page").find('.car_detail').attr("src", this.src);
});
```

If the .detail_img elements are being used for the car_detail image then you can simplify the above code to:

```
$(".detail_img").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("div.page").find('.car_detail').attr("src", this.src);
});
```

Comment: thanks! I did exactly you said, and like I supposed it just affect the first #car_detail, in the first #page. If I clcick on a thumb int the second #page the action will occur in the first #car_detail, and not just in the second #car_detail. I dont know if I explain my point very well, but I have more than one #car_detail. if I use .car_detail, it affects all the car_detail once

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the .car_detail too?

Comment: it is in my first post - third line. All the html block will be repeated. I hope I'm being enlightening. Any questions...feel free to ask. Thanks a lot

Comment: weird, but it doesn't work in any case. I put an alert after the function() and in the second case it doesn't show Up

Comment: @user794035: Updated the post and also added a working example. Pls check

Answer (score 1):

You need to give [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) to your children nodes:

```
 $('.page').each(function(i) {
        $('.areaThumb', this).each(function(j) {
            $('.detail_img', this).eq(j).click(function(){
                $('.car_detail', this).eq(i).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
            });
        });
});
```

Every *this* is pointing to the current element given by the jquery function that called it.

[edit] Cybernate found a better way to do what you wanted to. My answer mostly explains why your code did not work as you wanted

Comment: thanks, but it is not working :( I think the problem may be on the last part:  $('.car_detail', this)....

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong approach about this,

You should just use cloning and you will be fine...

**HTML**

```
<div class="holder">Replace Me</div>
<div>
    <div class="car"><img src="img1" /></div>
    <div class="car"><img src="img2" /></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.car').click(function(){//when you click the .car div or <img/>
    var get_car =   $(this).clone();//copy .car and clone it and it's children 
    $('.holder').html('').append(get_car);//put the clone to the holder div...
});
```

I think this is what you should be doing, simple and elegant... do not understand why you complicate as much :)